# PHP preg_match_all - what's wrong with this regex?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

Suppose I have the following in a text file:

```
xxa name="round_xx
Number 1
xxcolspanxx
DOG

yya name="round_yy
Number 2
xxcolspanxx
DOG

zza name="round_zz
Number 3
xxcolspanxx
DOG
```

I want to use PHP's **preg_match_all()** function to  return all sequences within the text file that start with:

> **a name="round_**

.. has any sequence of characters and newlines in between, and then ends with:

> **colspan**

So the result should be these 3 matches:

```
a name="round_xx
Number 1
xxcolspan
```

```
a name="round_yy
Number 2
xxcolspan
```

```
a name="round_zz
Number 3
xxcolspan
```

This is my code, which fails. It reads the contents of the text file in to $page_contents, but the preg_match_all is producing totally incorrect matches:

```
$page_contents = file_get_contents('./path/to/textfile.txt');
$matches1 = array();
preg_match_all('/a name="round_(.*)colspan/s', $page_contents, $matches1);
```

I'm using PHP 7.1.28, Windows 10. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the regex non greedy:

```
preg_match_all('/a name="round_(.*?)colspan/s', $page_contents, $matches1);
//                              __^
```